# How to obtain Accuracy of Feature Selection methods?

Tags: feature-selection, accuracy

I used the following methods:

Variance_Threshold: `selecto_vth = VarianceThreshold(threshold=1.0)`

ANOVA: `anova = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k=20)`

Mutual_Information: `fs_mutual = SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif, k=20)`

Sequential_Feature_Selector: `sfs = SequentialFeatureSelector(RandomForestClassifier(), n_features_to_select=20, scoring='accuracy')`

But I did not find how to get the their Accuracy, unlike Recursive Feature Elimination:

```
print(accuracy_score(y_test, rfe.predict(x_test))) # it worked
```

Comment: one way is to create a model with the (best) selected features and measure the accuracy of the model

Comment: Dear @NikosM. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (I know no other way, btw) is to create a model with the (best) selected features and measure the accuracy of that model.

This accuracy will be parametrised by the model you used. For example, using a different model might alter the accuracy, so using a handful of models and getting the average will give you a hint of the accuracy of the features selected.

This procedure is **exactly similar** to the procedure followed by [sklearn.feature_selection.RFE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) where a model (an estimator) is passed as parameter.